# Highcharts: Hide/remove values (in a range) from y axis

Tags: highcharts

How can I remove some values from a yAxis?

My chart is a columnrange (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange) with days on the x axis (actually y axis, rotated), and I don't want show values for some days.

More in general I want hide some values from domain, i.e. a discontinuous domain.

Example:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: { type: 'columnrange', inverted: true },
    xAxis: { categories: [ 'FirstTask' ] },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: 24 * 36e5
    },
    plotOptions: {
        columnrange: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () { return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e.%b', this.y); }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{ data: [1497718538701, 1498150538701] }],
});
```

This code generates a chart with horizontal bar and days from 17 June to 22 June on x Axis (y, rotated).

I want remove days 19 and 20, i.e. all points in interval

```
[1497891338701, 1497977738701]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: please edit the title specifying that it's a highcharts related question, and provide an example of what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use broken axis module to set [breaks](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.breaks) on an axis.

```
yAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  tickInterval: 24 * 36e5,
  breaks: [{
    from: Date.UTC(2017, 5, 19),
    to: Date.UTC(2017, 5, 20),
    breakSize: 0
  }],
```

It seems that in your case some ticks are overlapping, but it might be fixed with [axis.labels.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.labels.formatter) - you can check if the value is outside the break.

```
  labels: {
    formatter: function () {
      const hide = Date.UTC(2017, 5, 19) <= this.value && this.value < Date.UTC(2017, 5, 20)

      return !hide ? this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this) : null
    }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/qhrd9wnw/